Why do I get linker error instead of no input error
I get linker error on clang command even if I did not provide any source codes.
$ clang
/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld.bfd: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

$ clang --version
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/lib/llvm/18/bin
Configuration file: /etc/clang/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-clang.cfg

$ clang -v
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/lib/llvm/18/bin
Configuration file: /etc/clang/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-clang.cfg
System configuration file directory: /etc/clang
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld.bfd" --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -pie -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib -z relro -z now -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld.bfd: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It does its work if I pass source code but it is odd. Should it print no input error instead like gcc does?
$ gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

I am using gentoo so maybe my USE flag thingy causes this problem?
Or is this normal behavior?
And my USE flags just in case:
$ emerge --info | grep ^USE
USE="X acl amd64 bzip2 cet cjk crypt dbus elogind gdbm grub iconv ipv6 libtirpc multilib ncurses nls openmp pam pcre pipewire pulseaudio readline screencast seccomp ssl test-rust unicode v4l vaapi wayland xattr zlib" ABI_X86="64" ADA_TARGET="gcc_12" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_anon authn_dbm authn_file authz_dbm authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="karbon sheets words" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="mmx mmxext sse sse2 aes avx avx2 f16c fma3 pclmul popcnt rdrand sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock greis isync itrax mtk3301 ntrip navcom oceanserver oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 tsip tripmate tnt ublox" GRUB_PLATFORMS="efi-64" GUILE_SINGLE_TARGET="3-0" GUILE_TARGETS="3-0" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb text" LUA_SINGLE_TARGET="lua5-1" LUA_TARGETS="lua5-1" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php8-2" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres15" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_12" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_12" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby31 ruby32" VIDEO_CARDS="intel" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tarpit sysrq proto logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"

Thanks.

Which clang version do you have? Perhaps, it's a very outdated one. On my side clang 18.1 and gcc 14.2 give the same result which is the one you see on gcc on your side (no input files). You can check the version with $ clang --version

oh, i forgot to include version as well. it's 18.1.8.

What USE flags are you using?

This is most likely happening because your clang uses configuration file - /etc/clang/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-clang.cfg - and for some reason it invokes the compilation/linker all the time. Take a look at said file.

Also could you share a more detailed version output by typing $ clang -v ? It may tell more about the environment and clang setup.

# This configuration file is used by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-clang driver. @gentoo-common.cfg @gentoo-common-ld.cfg @gentoo-cet.cfg

so this is the config file and when i comment out @gentoo-common-ld.cfg the error gone away. maybe that was the case. but why does it invoke the linker by default?

anyway, i think it is not actual problem and clang on my machine works properly, i guess. thank you for your helping :D

@S.Y.Kim I was able to find this issue. Seems it's actually a clang bug. Added answer below with references.

This is a known clang issue.
It is happening because Gentoo's clang installation uses configuration file which under the hood adds linker flags like -Wl,-z,now
Please see:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/67209
https://www.reddit.com/r/Gentoo/comments/1bszw1l/bfd_ld_linker_is_giving_weird_errors_when/

